# Block in sidebar - where to put the logic?

Tags: forms, symfony

I would like to create a jumpbox block with some form and put it within the layout sidebar. The form will be have an entity select and exactly the Go button.
Base on the documentation I need to render the form template by using `{{ render(controller(...)) }}`, but I really don't where tu put the form logic.

It is good to create a method in the controller that use entities from the select? but it looks I need to create two methods, the first one for form rendering (without any route) and the second one for the form submit request (with route for "POST" method)?

Can somebody provide me some tips how to do it right way?

Comment: I tend to have the `CommonController` for things like those...

Comment: @jperovic ok, but in this case I need to get the current route in this action to correctly redirect users after the form submit. Save the route as a hidden field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need a controller as you sad, this will render this part of the sidebar, and the action should be the same controller, so just simply create a router for it.

And you were also sad right, create a hidden field and set there the current route. But this is the tricky part, cause when you call this "sub" render, inside the controller the route will be always, what is the route for the controller, so what you need to do, when you render the controller you need to pass in a variable what is the current route, what you can do easily by passing the `{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}` variable value, what is the NAME of the route, and then in your controller, at the end you return a new `RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl($url))`.

And both, the render of the form and the "process" can be in the same controller, or if you prefer it, you can take it apart, but I would use only one, and you can test from the request, what is the current method, if POST then you will search for the variable and set the session/cookie/ what do you have.

EDIT:

Even though you didn't like, you have to say it's a good answer, but here is an other one.
The action should be always the current route, and basically you need to set up a request event listener. Check there if it's a post method and if yes, then look for your specific key, and there you go. Both is equally good and I used both of them.

Comment: I've consulted it with my friends and they said exactly the same. However, I don't like the step with passing the `app.request.attributes.get('_route')` value for the controller method in view files. It's not cool for me :/.

Comment: I found that we shouldn't `app.request.attributes.get('_route')` -> https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/854

Comment: Well if you see also, that's a 3 year old comment, symfony changed a lot during the time. And that's also a reliable option. But i will present an other way-